# How to clip rendering in OpenGL (C++)

Tags: c++, opengl, graphics

How to clip rendering in OpenGL (simple rectangle area)?
Please post a C++ example.

Comment: It's probably better to describe what you've tried, if anything, than to simply ask for example code.  Here's a link to the OpenGL Red Book, which is free online and probably has information about what you're looking for. http://www.glprogramming.com/red/

Comment: Thank you for the link. I've played with glFrustum, projections etc., but too long ago. I would like to recieve a nice simple example of clipping.

Answer (score 7):

What you probably need is OpenGL's [scissor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd368581(VS.85).aspx) mechanism.

It **clips rendering of pixels that do not fall into a rectangle** defined by `x`, `y`, `width` and `height` parameters.

Note also that this OpenGL state when enabled, affects `glClear` command by restricting the area cleared.

Comment: how do you prevent all future-rendered scene objects from being clipped by that clipping rectangle?  In other words, if you only wanted to apply that clipping rectangle for children of a GUI element but then wanted to render other objects in the scene, how would you prevent all other objects from being clipped by that rectangle?

Comment: I don't know exactly what you mean, but common practice is to separate 3D rendering from GUI rendering by using FBO and passes.

Answer (score 2):

If you only want to display a specific rectangle, you need a combination of something like `glFrustrum` or `glOrtho` along with `glViewPort`. It's actually `glViewPort` that sets the clipping rectangle. `glFrustrum`, `glOrtho` (`gluPerspective`, etc.) then map some set of real coordinates to that rectangle. Typically you hardly notice the `glViewPort`, because it's normally set to the entire area of whatever window you're using, and what you change is the mapping to get different views in the window.

If you just adjust `glFrustum` (for example) by itself, the display area on the screen will stay the same, and you'll just change the mapping so you'll still fill the entire window area, and basically just move the virtual camera around, so you zoom in or out (etc.) on the "world" being displayed. Conversely, if you just adjust `glViewPort`, you'll display exactly the same data, but into a smaller rectangle.

To "clip" the data to the smaller rectangle, you need to adjust both at once, in more or less the "opposite" directions so as your view-port rectangle gets smaller, you zoom in your view frustum to compensate.